# Currency exchange rate java assignment

Tags: java

Hello I am looking for help on my homework assignment!
So the prompt is as follows:

" Write a program that prompts the user to enter the exchange rate from currency in US dollars to Chinese RMB. Prompt the user to enter 0 to convert from US dollars to Chinese RMB and 1 to convert from Chinese RMB to US dollars. Prompt the user to enter the amount in US dollars or Chinese RMB to convert it to Chinese RMB or US dollars, respectively. When the user enters "1" (yuans to dollars) the program should extract the dollar amount before the decimal point, and the cents after the decimal amount using the indexOf() and substring() methods.Here are the sample runs, user's input is underlined:

Enter the exchange rate from dollars to RMB: 6.81
Enter 0 to convert dollars to RMB and 1 vice versa: 0
Enter the dollar amount: 100
$100.0 is 681.0 yuan.
Enter the exchange rate from dollars to RMB: 6.81
Enter 0 to convert dollars to RMB and 1 vice versa: 1
Enter the yuan amount: 1000
1000.0 yuan is $146.843 dollar
 146 dollars
 3 quarters
 0 dimes
 1 nickel
 4 pennies"

So i got my code to do all of the things before it separates the money into cent US cent values. This is where my problem comes in, I don't know how to work with the decimal values (or cents) to make it display how many of each are in the amount. 
This is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LabTask6 {
private static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double exchangeRate = 0;
    int conversion;
    double dollar = 0;
    double yuan = 0;
    String Dollar = " ";
    int quarter = 0;


    System.out.print("Enter the exchange rate from dollars to RMB: ");
    exchangeRate = key.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter 0 to convert dollars to RMB or "
            + " 1 for RMB to dollars: ");
    conversion = key.nextInt();


    //while(conversion == 0 || conversion == 1) {
    if(conversion == 0) {
        System.out.print("Enter the dollar amount: ");
        dollar = key.nextDouble();
        yuan = dollar * exchangeRate;

        System.out.println("$" + dollar + " is " + yuan + " yuan.");
        System.out.println();

    }else if(conversion == 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter the Yuan amount: ");
        yuan = key.nextDouble();
        dollar = yuan / exchangeRate;

        System.out.printf(yuan + " yuan is%8.3f dollars.", dollar);
        System.out.println();

        Dollar = dollar + "";
        System.out.println(Dollar.substring(0, Dollar.indexOf(".")) + " dollars");
    }

}

}
```

As you can see, in the second if statement i tried to get the "dollar" amount by converting the number into a string and displaying only the things from index(0) to the '.' char. However that will not work for the rest of the required items like nickels, dimes, quarters, and pennies.
My initial idea was to make a while loop that prevented the decimals (cents) from reaching zero and incrementing the cent value, declared as variables, so long as they were divisible by the cent value i.e. number was 126.47, i would take the 47 and see if it was divisible by 25 then if the result was >0 then it would add 1 to quarter, or quarter++. Two problems come up with this, one is that the end value would not be 47 cents, and also that i am trying to figure out how to isolate and manipulate those cent values in the first place.
I know i wrote a freaking essay but i am completely stumped now, and i was trying to be as clear as possible, can anyone help?

Recap, i want to print the dollar, quarter, nickel, dime, and penny amounts. but have no clue how.

Comment: Ignore the while loop towards the top i forgot to delete that.

Comment: Walk yourself through the steps you would use to do it then think about how you can program an algorithm to do the same steps. Think about the fact that you have a fixed number of coins to deal with and they have a fixed value - 25, 10, 5, 1. Write out the math somewhere to make sure you understand how it will work and/or try to solve small pieces first (e.g. figure out how to calculate just the number of quarters needed then add more coins later)

Comment: Best way to get the "cents" out of `dollar`, since `dollar` is a `double`: (1) Multiply by 100 to get the total number of cents, which could be > 100 (2) Use `Math.round()` to convert to an integer (3) Use the `%` operator--I'll let you figure out how.  You need to use `round` because `double` cannot represent most dollar values exactly, and multiplying by 100 could give you an answer that's a little less or a little more than the actual integer value.

Comment: I wrote the above before realizing that the assignment asked you to use a substring to extract the cents.  I think that is a really bad way to do things.  So now you know what the right way to do it is, even if you can't use it on this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code for you to look at. Note that I renamed your `Dollar` variable to `dollarStr` since variables shouldn't begin with a capital letter per [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). I also want to point out that ajb is quite correct in that using `double` to represent currency is not a good idea. However, since this is a simple homework assignment I doubt that it's going to be an issue for you.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

...

public static void main(String[] args){
    //omitting extra code to shorten the answer
    ...

    }else if(conversion == 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter the Yuan amount: ");
        yuan = key.nextDouble();
        dollar = yuan / exchangeRate;

        System.out.printf(yuan + " yuan is%8.3f dollars.", dollar);
        System.out.println();

        dollarStr = String.valueOf(dollar);
        System.out.println(dollarStr.substring(0, dollarStr.indexOf(".")) + " dollars");

        //Get the "cents" part of the converted value
        String centsStr = dollarStr.substring(dollarStr.indexOf("."));
        //Convert the value into a double
        double cents = Double.parseDouble(centsStr);
        //Multiplying by 100 so that something like 0.173 dollars 
        // becomes 17.3 cents
        cents *= 100;

        //Assuming you want to round to nearest penny, 
        //  but it's unclear from your question if this is correct.
        cents = Math.round(cents); 

        //quick and dirty conversion of the rounded cents to an integer value
        int change = (int) cents;

        //For demonstration purposes, feel free to remove it.
        System.out.println(cents+ " cents");

        //Calculate how many of each kind of coin and display results.
        Map<Coin, Integer> changeMap = makeChange(change);
        for(Coin coin: changeMap.keySet()){
            int numCoins = changeMap.get(coin);
            System.out.print(numCoins +" "+ (numCoins != 1 ? coin.getPlural() : coin.name().toLowerCase())+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}

//Calculates the number of each kind of Coin to use
// in order to make the specified amount of change.
public static Map<Coin,Integer> makeChange(int cents){
    Map<Coin,Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
    for(Coin coin: Coin.values()){
        int numCoins = cents/coin.getValue();
        cents = cents % coin.getValue();

        results.put(coin, numCoins);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Here is the `Coin` [enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) that goes along with the above code:

```
public enum Coin {
    QUARTER(25, "quarters"), DIME(10, "dimes"), NICKEL(5, "nickels"), PENNY(1, "pennies");

    private int value;
    private String plural;

    private Coin(int val, String plur){
        value = val;
        plural = plur;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public String getPlural(){
        return plural;
    }
}
```

If you're not comfortable with enums then feel free to convert that into a traditional class and define some constants instead.

Some things you still need to worry about are:

1. Testing your code thoroughly
2. Handling bad user input - negative numbers, strings instead of numbers, etc.

Comment: Hey D.B. I got my code to work using the suggestions from earlier, yours included. my code works fine now, The sample codes you provided are really nice and i would like to study them a bit more and try to play around with it. However the things you used are a little too advanced for where we are at in the course so it wouldn't really help me for this specific assignment, but like i said i can play around with this code and just learn what i can from it for the time being. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Glad to help. I wasn't sure how much you knew about the principles of Object Oriented Programming but I thought this would be a great chance for you to see how it could be implemented using a more object oriented approach. For some further reading you could take a look at the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/)